# "View video url" sometimes not shown

Tags: flash, url

Instead of using a screen recorder, I like to record streams by using Tor Browser to "right click" on where the video should be (I think the site uses flash player), view Video URL and open and record with VLC player.

However, sometimes I find that the "empty box" where the video should be is not there. And there is no place to right click to Copy Video URL even though it is the same site. It sometimes requires me to exit and restart Tor Browser multiple times until the "empty box" appears. Is there a reason why I am experiencing this issue? Sorry I'm not IT savvy so the terms I'm using may not be most accurate.